# Can't resolve XmlDictionaryWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I have some VB.NET code that I am converting to C#. It uses `XmlDictionaryWriter` and XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas both of which, according to MSDN are in System.Xml and in the assembly `System.Runtime.Serialization`. I added `System.Runtime.Serialization` as a reference. It keeps saying they cannot be found. Here is the VB.NET code:

```
Dim xmlreader As System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader

Dim quotas As New System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas

xmlreader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(result, quotas)
```

This is in VS2013/.NET Framework 4

Comment: Have you included a proper using statement at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

Comment: How can I delete this post? I screwed up. I added System.Runtime.Serializatiuon to the wrong namespace

Comment: There should be a delete button under the tags of your question.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization` should do the trick.

Comment: But Why its required

Comment: @kbvishnu C# using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your References folder under Project and add Reference, left side under Assembly click Framework then right side search box type System.Runtime.Serialization, check the check box and click add. It should get add into your project. In .cs file add using System.Runtime.Serialization should solve your problem.

[image]